# Finding the matrix representation of $T$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose that $T \in \mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R^n};\mathbb{R^m})$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $T(1,1) = (3,\pi,0)$ and $T(0,1) = (4,0,1)$. Find the matrix representation of $T$.

So I know exactly what this is going to look like in matrix form, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct here. So since we have $T(1,1) = (3,\pi,0)$, we get that the column vector from this is given as
\begin{bmatrix}
           3 \\
           \pi \\
           0
           \\
         \end{bmatrix}
A similar reasoning shows what the other column vector is, however, what's the logic behind this and how is it determined? I was thinking that we just obtain the column vector by looking at what $T$ is equivalent to.

Comment: $n=2$ and $m=3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are interested in the matrix representation of a linear transformation, we have to choose a basis for the domain and the counter domain. At your case, it has been given the value of $T$ at the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$, whose images are described in terms of the standard basis $\mathcal{B}_{2} = \{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

If your are interested in the representation of $T$ in terms of $\mathcal{B}_{1} = \{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, notice that
\begin{align*}
T(1,0) = T((1,1) - (0,1)) = T(1,1) - T(0,1) = (-1,\pi,-1)
\end{align*}

Consequently, the sought matricial representation is given by:
\begin{align*}
[T]_{\mathcal{B}_{1}}^{\mathcal{B}_{2}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 4\\
\pi & 0\\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps.